# How to append a underlined word to a list?

Tags: python, list, append, ansi-escape

I want to append a consonant letter to a list, but whenever I do, I keep getting the ANSI code in the list. Any idea on how to do it?

```
underline = "\x1B[4m"
end = "\033[0m"

def findConsonant(word):
    new_word = []
    for letter in word:
        #if letter is a consonate, underline
        if letter in consonants:
            letter = underline + letter + end
            new_word.append(letter)
        else:
            #If not do nothing
            new_word.append(letter)
            print(letter)
    print(new_word)
```

output for the word "papel" (paper in Spanish)

```
a
e
['\x1b[4mp\x1b[0m', 'a', '\x1b[4mp\x1b[0m', 'e', '\x1b[4ml\x1b[0m']
```

Comment: Please update to make this a fully running example and include the output you get. you are printing the list, which will give you the "repr" of the list, not its printable "str" representation.

Comment: Still doesn't work and I'm not going to fill out the missing lines for you. But change that to `print("".join(new_word))` and you'll see the string you want.

Comment: please help me i still dont think I understand what you are saying, I tried to use slicing but it didn't work out for me. Ill give you the info you need. @tdelaney

Comment: When you print a list of strings, you get the literal representation of the string (the same as if you typed it into a python program). If you want the string representation, you need to loop through the list. The print I showed does that. Replace the current `print(new_word)` and see if you like the result. And try copy/paste of your entire example into a separate .ply file, then try to run it. It will fail. Add the few lines needed to make it work.

Comment: you are a life saver! my code works now ahhaha. i was over exaggerating this problem. Now I have a new problem, I want to use this word in another function to locate syllables but when I do I keep on getting this error. "  File "c:\Users\shakt\Syllabification-and-Accentuation\main.py", line 97, in <module>
    createSyllable(name)
  File "c:\Users\shakt\Syllabification-and-Accentuation\main.py", line 75, in createSyllable
    for letter in word:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable". My code is on https://github.com/shakthepro/Syllabification-and-Accentuation

Comment: That could be a new question on stack overflow - but notice that findConstant does not return the string. It returns None which is what your new problem says is wrong